# Vagrant provision, not able to start grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, vagrant

I am trying to have vagrant install all that is needed for nodejs to run properly. Then after doing a 'nohup grunt server &' on the root folder of the node project I was expecting for the server to be up listening at port 3030 but it's not.

If right after provisioning I do 
vagrant ssh
grunt server &

all works as it should. It's only when the provisioner runs it that it doesn't work.

Here's part of my Vagrantfile:

```
git clone https://github.com/airbnb/rendr.git
cd /home/temp/rendr/examples/00_simple/
npm install
cp -rf /home/temp/rendr/examples/00_simple/ /home/website/nodejs/rendr-try1
cd /home/website/nodejs/rendr-try1/00_simple
nohup grunt server &
```

So it definitely seems to be related to the provisioner not running in a terminal, but is there any easy way to get this running without using something like upstart ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok found this out.

It turns out whatever process that wants to stay running has to be properly daemonized. In order to do this one must detach stdin, stdout and stderr.

I was doing

```
"nohup grunt server &"
```

to start node.js through grunt
Replacing it with:

```
"nohup grunt server 0<&- &>/dev/null &"
```

works perfectly